# unexpected state 'TERMINATING', wanted target 'RUNNING, WAITING'. last error: INTERNAL_ERROR: Failed to start the job flow due to an internal error

Tags: cluster-computing, amazon-emr

getting this error while creating emr cluster in aws
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUqmz.png)

│ Error: waiting for EMR Cluster (j-3xxxxxxxxxx) to create: unexpected state 'TERMINATING', wanted target 'RUNNING, WAITING'. last error: INTERNAL_ERROR: Failed to start the job flow due to an internal error
need help resolving the error

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest reviewing any EMR cluster logs in S3 (if logging enabled) and EC2 instance system log of created instances. If you have AWS Support Plan, contact them for more details.